# Qlik Sense API offline mode

Tags: api, qliksense

I am building an app in Angular consuming data from Qlik Sense dashboards using the API. Ideally there would be a way for the user to still navigate the app and see the data even if they are offline (no internet connection).

I've read that in the [official Qlik app there is a way to download the data](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Mobile/working-with-mobile.htm):

`Download apps on your device to access them at any moment without the need for an internet connection`

But so I am wondering if this would be possible as well using the Qlik API and what would it take?